# Why is this jQuery code not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple tool tip function (I'm trying to learn jQuery so please don't suggest plugins for this). When I write it like this it works:

```
             $('span.toolTip').hide();
             function toolTip() {
                $('.targetLink').mouseover(function() {                
                    $('.toolTip').show().html('Hello there');
                });
            }

            <span class='toolTip'></span>
            <a href="#" class="targetLink">Hover over me</a>
```

But when I try to pass parameters through the function it doesn't work:

```
    $('span.toolTip').hide();
    function toolTip(target, tooltip, message) {
        var target = '.' + target;
        $(target).mouseover(function() {
            var tooltip = '.' + tooltip;
            $(tooltip).show().html(message);
        });
    }

    toolTip('targetLink', 'toolTip', 'Hello There');

    <span class='toolTip'></span>
    <a href="#" class="targetLink">Hover over me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're "hiding" the `target` parameter with a new local `target` variable:

```
function toolTip(target, tooltip, message) {
    // this target is not the same as the parameter target
    var target = '.' + target;
```

Simply remove the `var` and it should work:

```
function toolTip(target, tooltip, message) {
    target = '.' + target;
    ...
```

Comment: +1. This is the problem. Sometimes it's called variable shadowing. Another solution would just be to use a differently-named variable rather than remove the `var`, e.g. `function toolTip(target, tooltip, message) { var targetSelector = '.' + target; ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the right [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) since the variable is `undefined`, it should be:

```
function toolTip(target, tooltip, message) {
    $('.' + target).mouseover(function() {
        $('.' + tooltip).show().html(message);
    });
}
```

Currently you're creating a *new* variable...not resulting in the correct selector.  [You can test the updated/working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PTbjX/).

Comment: He's adding the . in the function: `target = '.' + target`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because variable `tooltip` is undefined.

```
$(target).mouseover(function() {
    var tooltip = '.' + tooltip;
    alert(tooltip); //undefined
    $(tooltip).show().html(message);
});
```

See error in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDVtb/).

**EDIT**

You're getting undefined, as @nick said, because you're creating a new local variable using the keyword `var` in `var tooltip`. So, to fix, remove `var` and you will get the external variable ([closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#JavaScript)).

See correct code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDVtb/1/).

```
$(target).mouseover(function() {
    tooltip = '.' + tooltip;
    $(tooltip).show().html(message);
});
```